# Why should I choose combinators over class construction for JSON serialisation?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

The Play Scala documentation shows how to serialise JSON in two ways, first:

```
implicit val locationWrites = new Writes[Location] {
    def writes(location: Location) = Json.obj(
        "lat" -> location.lat,
        "long" -> location.long
    )
}
```

Then with combinators:

```
implicit val locationWrites: Writes[Location] = (
    (JsPath \ "lat").write[Double] and
    (JsPath \ "long").write[Double]
)(unlift(Location.unapply))
```

What reasons should be considered to choose one approach over the other?

Comment: For me there's not much to choose between the two. However, for case classes I'd go with the macro version instead: `implicit val locationWrites = Json.writes[Location]` (or `Json.format` for a `Format`).

Comment: It's a matter of taste, but the first is built on implicit conversions (ugh), while the second is built on type class instances. The second is (arguably) more complex for simple problems, but it also gives you a lot more power when you need it.